# 404 Not Found

Tags: php

希望　ログインページlogin.html.twigを表示させたい
エラー　404 Not Found 　var_dumpなどをして、NULL NULL 404 Not Found404 Not Foundが出ます。
ビギナーレベルです

NULL NULL 404 Not Found404 Not Foundを解消してログインページを正しく表示させたい

#### 前提

anyaddressという下記のようなポートフォリオを作成しています。

ゴール
anyaddress 完成　　anyaddress＝ユーザーが登録して、ログインすると住居が見れる　
住居はユーザーが投稿したもののリスト　住居を見て詳細を閲覧できる　詳細から予約ができる　予約するとユーザーが予約したリストが見れる
ログインしていれば投稿できるアプリケーション

【画面とその遷】関係するページのみ

ログインページ

ユーザー名とパスワードの入力フィールド
[ログイン]ボタン　一覧ページへ遷移
[新規登録]リンク　新規登録ページへ遷移

【各ディレクトリ、ファイルの内容】　関係するファイルのみ

Bootstrap.class.php: オートローダーやその他の設定を含む設定ファイル
PDODatabase.class.php: データベース関連の処理を行うクラスファイル

Modelディレクトリ
User.class.php: ユーザーモデルを表すクラスファイル
Session.class.php　セッション関係のクラスファイル

Controllerディレクトリ
UserController.php: ユーザー関連の処理を行うコントローラーファイル

Viewディレクトリ
login.html.twig: ログインページの表示を行うビューファイル
register.html.twig: 新規登録ページの表示を行うビューファイル

publicディレクトリ
ルーテイングの設定をindex.php

DB情報になります

テーブル

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_anyaddress_db |
+-------------------------+
| books                   |
| homes                   |
| users                   |
| sessions                |
+-------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

カラム　データ型、制約、主キーなど

```
MariaDB [anyaddress_db]> DESCRIBE books;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| home_id | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date    | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| guests  | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.022 sec)

MariaDB [anyaddress_db]> DESCRIBE homes;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| address | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| image   | blob          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title   | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price   | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.031 sec)

MariaDB [anyaddress_db]> DESCRIBE users;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.026 sec)

MariaDB [anyaddress_db]> DESCRIBE sessions;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| session_key | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| home_id     | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| guests      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.014 sec)
```

下記は関係するであろうコードになります。

```
<?php
/*
  * ファイルパス : C:\xampp\htdocs\anyaddress\Bootstrap.class.php
  * ファイル名 : Bootstrap.class.php(設定に関するプログラム)
  */
namespace anyaddress;
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

class Bootstrap
{
    const DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    const DB_NAME = 'anyaddress_db';
    const DB_USER = 'anyaddress_user';
    const DB_PASS = 'anyaddress_pass';
    const DB_TYPE = 'mysql';
    const APP_DIR = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/anyaddress/';
    const TEMPLATE_DIR = self::APP_DIR . 'View/';
    const CACHE_DIR = false; 
    const APP_URL = 'http://localhost/anyaddress/'; // プロジェクトのURL
    const ENTRY_URL = self::APP_URL;

    public static function loadClass($class)
    {
        $path = str_replace('\\', '/', self::APP_DIR . $class . '.class.php');
    require_once $path;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register([
    'anyaddress\Bootstrap',
    'loadClass'
]);
```

```
<?php
/*
  * ファイルパス : C:\xampp\htdocs\anyaddress\public\index.php
  * ファイル名 : index.php(ルーテイング設定に関するプログラム)
  */
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  require_once __DIR__ . '/../Bootstrap.class.php';
  use anyaddress\Bootstrap;
  use anyaddress\Controller\HomeController;
  use anyaddress\Controller\BookController;
  use anyaddress\Controller\UserController;
  
  // リクエストURIの取得
  $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  
  // ルーティング設定
  $routes = [
      '/View/login' => [UserController::class, 'login'],
      '/View/register' => [UserController::class, 'register'],
      '/View/homelist(\d+)' => [HomeController::class, 'homelist'],
      '/View/detail' => [HomeController::class, 'detail'],
      '/view/book' => [BookController::class, 'book'],
      '/View/complete' => [BookController::class, 'complete'],
      '/view/booklist(\d+)' => [BookController::class, 'booklist'],
      '/View/post' => [HomeController::class, 'post']
  ];
  
  // ルーティングに応じたコントローラーとアクションの取得
  $controller = null;
  $action = null;
  foreach ($routes as $route => $handler) {
      if (strpos($uri, $route) === 0) {
          $controller = new $handler[0]();
          $action = $handler[1];
          break;
      }
  }
  
  // コントローラーとアクションの確認
var_dump($controller, $action);

// コントローラーとアクションの実行
try {
    if ($controller !== null && $action !== null) {
        $controller->$action();
    } else {
        echo '404 Not Found';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // エラーメッセージを表示するか、エラーログを記録するなどの処理
    echo 'エラーが発生しました: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

  // コントローラーとアクションの実行
  try {
      if ($controller !== null && $action !== null) {
          $controller->$action();
      } else {
          echo '404 Not Found';
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      // エラーメッセージを表示するか、エラーログを記録するなどの処理
      echo 'エラーが発生しました: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```

```
<?php
/*
 * ファイルパス :C:\xampp\htdocs\anyaddress\Model\User.class.php
 * ファイル名 :User.class.php(ユーザーに関するプログラムのクラスファイル、Model)
 */
namespace anyaddress\Model;

class User
{
    private $db;
    private $session;

    public function __construct($db, $session)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        if (empty($username)|| empty($password)) {
            return false;
        }

        $table = 'users';
        $column = 'id, username, password';
        $where = 'username = ?';
        $arrVal = [$username];

        $userData = $this->db->select($table, $column, $where, $arrVal);

        // ユーザー名に対応するユーザー情報が存在しない場合はログイン失敗
        if(empty($userData)) {
            return false;
        }

        // パスワードのハッシュをデータベースから取得したユーザー情報と比較
        if(password_verify($passowrd, $userData[0]['passoword'])) {
            // ログイン成功時にSessionクラスのcheckSessionメソッドを呼び出す
            $this->session->checkSession();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userData[0]['id'];
            return $userData[0]['id'];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        
        var_dump($controller, $action);

    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return isset($_SESSION['user_id']);

    }


    public function logout()
    {
        // セッションを破棄してログアウトする
        session_destroy();
    }

    

    public function register($username, $password)
    {
        // パスワードのハッシュ化
        $hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        // ユーザー情報を登録する
        $table = 'users';
        $insData = [
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $hashedPassword
            
        ];
        return $this->db->insert($table, $insData);
    }

    public function getUser($userId)
    {
        // ユーザーIDに基づいて、指定されたユーザーの情報を取得するロジックを実装
        $table = 'users';
        $column = 'id, username, email';
        $where = 'id = ?';
        $arrVal = [$userId];
        
        // 取得したユーザー情報を返す
        $userData = $this->db->select($table, $column, $where, $arrVal);
        return $userData[0]??null;
    }    
}
```

```
<?php
 /*
  * 　ファイルパス : C:\xampp\htdocs\anyaddress/Controller/UserController.php
  * ファイル名 : UserController.php(ユーザー関連の処理を制御するコントローラー)
  * アクセスURL http://localhost/anyaddress/Controller/UserController.php
  */
namespace anyaddress\Controller;
  
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Bootstrap.class.php';
  use anyaddress\Bootstrap;
  use anyaddress\PDODatabase;
  use anyaddress\Model\Session;
  use anyaddress\Model\User;

  $db = new PDODatabase(Bootstrap::DB_HOST, Bootstrap::DB_USER, Bootstrap::DB_PASS, Bootstrap::DB_NAME, Bootstrap::DB_TYPE);
  $ses = new Session($db);
  $user = new User($db, $ses); // SessionクラスをUserクラスにインジェクション

  $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(Bootstrap::TEMPLATE_DIR);
  $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, ['cache' => Bootstrap::CACHE_DIR]);

  // セッションに、セッションIDを設定する
  $ses->checksSession();

  //ログインページ
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && !isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    // ログインしていない場合の処理
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('login.html.twig');
    $template->display();
    exit;
  } 

// ログインページからのPOSTリクエスト
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['login'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
      // ログイン成功した場合の処理
      header('Location: ' . Bootstrap::ENTRY_URL . 'homelist.html.twig');
      exit();
  } else {
      // ログイン失敗した場合の処理
      $loginError = true;
  }
}

// 新規登録ページ
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
  // ログインしている場合の処理
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('login.html.twig');
  $template->display();
  exit;
} else {
  // ログインしていない場合は新規登録ページを表示する
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('register.html.twig');
  $template->display();
  exit;
}


// 新規登録ページからのPOSTリクエスト
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['register'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($user->register($username, $password)) {
    // 登録成功した場合の処理
    $registrationSuccess = true;
} else {
    // 登録失敗した場合の処理
    $registrationError = true;
}
}

// Twigテンプレートにデータを渡して表示
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('login.html.twig');
$template->display([
'loginError' => $loginError ?? false,
]);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('register.html.twig');
$template->display([
  'registrationSuccess' => $registrationSuccess ?? false,
  'registrationError' => $registrationError ?? false
]);
```

login.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="{{constant('anyaddress\\Bootstrap::APP_URL')}}css/some-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h2>ログイン</<>h2>
        <form method="POST" action="{{constant('anyaddress\\Bootstrap::APP_URL')}}Controller/UserController.php">
            <div>
               <label for="username">ユーザー名:</label>
               <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">パスワード:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" name="login" value="ログイン">
            </div>
        </form>
        <p><a href="{{ constant('anyaddress\\Bootstrap::APP_URL') }}View/homelist.html.twig">一覧ページ</a></p>
        <p><a href="{{ constant('anyaddress\\Bootstrap::APP_URL') }}View/register.html.twig">新規登録</a></p>
　　</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Apache　error.log

```
[Wed Oct 04 16:46:37.292864 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4132:tid 352] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 04 16:46:37.379849 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 4132:tid 352] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Oct 04 16:46:37.471197 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4132:tid 352] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

#### 試したこと

DocumentRootが正しいか調べた

index.phpのBootstrap.class.phpのパスが正しいか調べた
index.phpのルーテイング設定に/View/  というパスを追加した

↓

アクセスURL `http://localhost/anyaddress/View/login` のログインページを表示させようとしたところ、NULL NULL 404 Not Found404 Not Foundというエラーが出ております。
404 not found という出力はindex.phpの61行目  echo '404 Not Found';　　の処理によるものです。

何卒よろしくお願いします。